# Is it possible that the errors are not evenly balanced by level, while the model is correct?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, polynomial, mgcv

My question is if the outcome of my model can be correct. I have two
independent continious variables (x1, x2) and one catagorical
independent variable (x3).  My dependent variable (y) is continious on
a scale from 1 to 100.
I have fitted a model mygam1 using bam from mgcv without using variabele x3:

```
    mygam1 <- bam(y ~ s(x1, k = 20) + s(x2, k = 20) + 
                    ti(x1, x2, k = c(10,10)),
                  method = 'REML',
                  data = partial_train_data_GAM)

    p1 <- predict(mygam1) # predict op traindata
    
    Verschil1 = p1 - partial_train_data_GAM$y
    
    train_data_incl <- cbind(partial_train_data_GAM, Verschil1)
    
    # Next I have grouped the residuals by x3 and calculated the mean:
    
    vb2 <- train_data_incl %>%
      group_by(x3) %>%
      summarize(Vers = round(mean(Verschil1)*100,1)) %>%
      arrange(desc(Vers))
    
    # The resulting average differences are used as a continous variable in the next fit of mygam2:
    
    train_data_incl <- left_join(train_data_incl, vb2, by = "x3")
    
    k_factor <- nlevels(train_data_incl[[x3]]) - 2
    
    
    mygam2 <- bam(y ~ s(x1, k = 20) + s(x2, k = 20) + 
                    s(Vers, k = k_factor) +
                    ti(x1, x2, k = c(10,10)),
                  method = 'REML',
                  data = train_data_incl)
    
    val_data_GAM <- left_join(val_data_GAM, vb2, by = "x3")

    p <- predict(mygam2, newdata = val_data_GAM) 


    my_error = p - y

    my_test <- val_data_GAM %>%
      dplyr::group_by(x3, my_error)  %>%  
      summarize(count = n())
```

This is done with 5 fold cv.
mygam1 and mygam2 are fitted on the same train partition.
At the end I have rowbind all 5 parts of predicted outcomes on the valuation data.

If I group the errors by x3, I can see the spread of the errors for every level of x3 (see table below). From this table I notice that there is a skew for most levels since for most levels the errors are not evenly balanced between below and above zero (zero is no error where p == y).

Is it possible that the errors are not evenly balanced by level, although the model is correct?

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: With regards to your model being correct, I'll quote George Box: "All models are wrong, but some are useful".  So the real questions is your model useful?

Comment: @ Dave2e Thank you for your remark. I agree all models are wrong, but can be useful. Adding x3 to the model is a significant improvement of the RMSE. I did find there is no correlation or pattern between the errors and x3. So probably I have to conclude that the imbalance is due to variance (in the predictions).